# How to detect loading of a page in a browser using windows phone app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm loading an url in my app using the following code,

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("https:www.myurl.com", UriKind.Absolute);
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

After giving some datas i'll be navigated to another page(response page).
How can i detect the loading of the response page??
How can i pause my execution of the code until the response page is loaded??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `WebBrowserTask` which is a Windows phone Launcher, here is a definition from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)  :

> The Launcher and Chooser APIs invoke distinct built-in applications
>   that replace the currently running application.

And here are some relevant details about them and related to your need:

> An important concept for Windows Phone application developers to
>   consider in general, and especially when using Launchers and Choosers,
>   is that the calling application is either put into a dormant state or
>   tombstoned when another application is launched. When the new task
>   application is launched, your application is deactivated and is no
>   longer running. Usually, your application is put into a dormant state
>   by the operating system. After completing the task, the user can
>   return to your application that was preserved in memory,

So when you launch a task (like `WebBrowserTask`) your application is no longer active, you just can't detect or do anything.

If you want to accomplish such a thing then you should check out the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). It is a complete WebBrowser that you can embed into your application (here is a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431807%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), it comes with lots of features like the [LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event that :

> Occurs after the WebBrowser control has loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accompolish the above mentioned task, i have used *WebBrowser* Control and added **LoadCompleted** Eventhandler.
The xaml code for that is,

```
 <phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" LoadCompleted="UriContentLoaded" x:Name="browserControl" />
```